# Mostrar a data do arquivo no PHP

Tags: php

estou tentando mostrar a data dos respectivos arquivos que estão dentro de um diretório, porém está mostrando apenas a data do ultimo arquivo em todos os arquivos... Alguma ideia?

```
<?php
$path = "arquivos/";
// Título
echo "<h2>Lista de Arquivos:</h2><br />";
// Abre a tabela, cria títulos
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Nome</th> ";
echo "<td> <th>Data</th> </td></tr>";

$data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", filemtime("$path"));
// Loop que gera registros
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {

if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

// Imprime linhas de registros
echo "<tr>
        <td>
            <a href='".$path.$fileInfo->getFilename() ."'>".$fileInfo->getFilename()."</a><br/>
        </td>
        <td>
       ".$data."
        </td>
      </tr>";
}
// Fecha a tabela
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Bom, a variável `$data` não é alterada dentro do laço de repetição, então é esperado que seja exibido o mesmo valor. Você não deveria atualizar o valor dela para cada arquivo?

Comment: A variável `$data` está retornando apenas a data da pasta em `$path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `$data` está estática pegando apenas a data da pasta atribuída na variável `$path`.

Use a função [**getMTime()**](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/directoryiterator.getmtime.php) para pegar as datas da última modificação dos arquivos e formate-as com `date()`.

Troque a linha:

```
".$data."
```

Por:

```
".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $fileInfo->getMTime())."
```

Comment: Obrigado, retirei a variável e coloquei direto como vc mostrou. Faltava o fileInfo rsrs